# SwiftUI Picker and NavigationLink Gesture Conflicts

Tags: swiftui

I have a situation when I have a picker inside of a NavigationLink. However, when changing the picker toggle it also triggers the NavigationLink and you are directed to a new screen. Here is some code:

```
enum OptionTypes:Int,CaseIterable {
    
    case option1
    case option2
    
    var title:String  {
        switch self {
        case .option1:
            return "Option 1"
        case .option2:
            return "Option 2"
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var pickerState:OptionTypes = .option1
    @State var isActive:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        NavigationView {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Destination(), isActive:$isActive) {
                
                Picker("Options", selection: self.$pickerState) {
                    ForEach(OptionTypes.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
                        Text(type.title)
                   }
               }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding()

            }
                        
        }
    }
}

struct Destination:View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
    
}
```

The ideal situation is to have Picker drag and tap gestures not fire off the NavgiationLink. I've tried varying permutations of `highPriorityGesture` and `simultaneousGesture` i.e. something like:

```
Picker("Options", selection: self.$pickerState) {
        ForEach(OptionTypes.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
                        Text(type.title)
        }
}
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
.highPriorityGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.1, coordinateSpace: .global).onEnded { _ in

})
```

But this route doesn't seem to work. I also tried having the NavigationLink make use of `isActive`. However, that also doesn't seem to be respected. It still navigates any way without me even making the `isActive` true. I'm now not sure on how to have a picker function independently from the NavigationLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `NavigationLink` separated from `Picker` in either way, like

1. Make invisible

   ```
   NavigationLink(destination: Destination(), isActive:$isActive) {
       EmptyView()
   }

   Picker("Options", selection: self.$pickerState) {
        ForEach(OptionTypes.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
            Text(type.title)
       }
   }
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    .padding()
   ```
2. In background

   ```
   Picker("Options", selection: self.$pickerState) {
        ForEach(OptionTypes.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
            Text(type.title)
       }
   }
   .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
   .padding()
   .background(
     NavigationLink(destination: Destination(), isActive:$isActive) {
       EmptyView()
     })
   ```